# Gruhapravesam in a week after marriage

Tags: belief, customs

Is it advisable to do Grihapravesham (Gruhapravesham - House worming function) immediately after marriage? Some of relatives are telling that it is not good to have another function immediately after marriage? Any specific reason for this?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan This is not off-topic